# How to fix the y-axis in matplotlib when creating a barchart such that it is in a descending order?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, x-axis

[image: See Screenshot]

Barchart should be plotted like this:

```
Axie Infinity: $4,074,436,594
Crypto Punks: $2,265,241,216
Bored Ape Yacht Club: $2,221,448,934
Mutant Ape Yacht Club: $1,566,494,617
Art Blocks: $1,265,723,876
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plt.gca().invert_xaxis()` to invert the x-axis.

Try this:

```
plt.bar(top5_Collections, top5_Sales)
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
plt.show()
```